# how to remove some meun item from contextmenu in my view

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I only put Add action in my context menu, it should only show "Add action" menu

But it also shows another menu (compare with -> add baseline)
I don't know where it is from and how to remove it or disable it?

Any hints will be more than welcome!

```java
    private void hookContextMenu() {
    MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
    menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {

            IStructuredSelection sSelection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer
                    .getSelection();

            Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection) sSelection)
                    .getFirstElement();
            if (obj.toString().equals("Repository")) {
                manager.add(addGitAction);
            }

        }
    });
    Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());

    viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
    menu.getItems();
    getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
}
```

Comment: Hint 1: use a spelling checker (look at the title). Hint 2: there are [tutorials](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-RCP-1/tutorial1.html). Present what advice you tried to follow, exactly how the result deviates from the desired effect. You are welcome to offer your thoughts as to the cause.

Comment: Show us how you are creating the menu. Are you calling `registerContextMenu`?

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```java
getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
```

tells Eclipse that this is the context menu for your part and that it should add contributions from other plugins which want to add themselves to all parts (or your part in particular).

You can leave this out if you don't want any contributions from other plugins.

Comment: if I do not call getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer); then contextmenu does not display at all. my class is  ConfigView extends ViewPart

Comment: How are you trying to display the menu? It should work fine right clicking on the viewer. Since you only add one action to the menu if the selection is 'Repository' the menu won't show when anything else is selected because it is empty.

Comment: when user right click button, it should only show Add Action, but currently it shows add action and also an unexpected one called Compare with API Base Line,

Comment: Yes, but without the registerContextMenu it should still show the Add Action (but only when the appropriate item is selected).

Comment: yes, it works now thanks! leave out getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer); is the solution for my problme